# Notice period and next relieving letter

Tags: human-resources

I informed my new employer that my last working day at my current employer would be the 4th June, however I had some outstanding work that lead to my employment there being extended by three days so my relieving letter date will show my last working day as being the 7th of June.

I'm due to start at my new employer on the 13th of June and I'm wondering if the leaving date mismatch between what I originally told them and the revised date that will be on the relieving letter will cause any problems?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78522/discussion-on-question-by-anil-notice-period-and-next-relieving-letter).

Comment: Hi Anil, your question is clear now. Thanks for the clarification. You should receive an answer soon. :)

Comment: I didn't get answer?

Comment: @Anil It's only been a couple of hours since the edited version was reopened... give people a chance to see it.

Comment: Could you clarify why you think this would be a problem and who would see it as a problem? I have no idea who you even think would care - some unemployment agency? Tax reasons? The new company?

Answer (score 4):

> I'm due to start at my new employer on the 13th of June and I'm wondering if the leaving date mismatch between what I originally told them and the revised date that will be on the relieving letter will cause any problems?

Unlikely. It doesn't come close to overlapping the start date with your new employer, so they've no particular reason to care. (If it did overlap, then it goes without saying it'd definitely be an issue you need to deal with.)

If you're worried it might cause issues, just send an email to HR (at the new company) saying that you agreed to stay at your old employer a couple of extra days, so your last day there will now be the 7th as oppose to the 4th. They can then update their records (if they need to), and you'll likely get a "thanks for letting me know" response.

Comment: One more question my salary will come on 6th but my last working day was 4th any problem will come on my relieving letter

Comment: I resigned on 5th may.

Comment: I did a 30 days of notice period till 4th june salary will come on 6th June any chances to get relieving letter date mismatch

Comment: @Anil You said your last working day was 7th, and that would appear in your relieving letter. Why do you now believe it would be 4th instead of 7th? Also, please focus on one question per post. If you have a different question, please post it as a separate question. Comments are meant to seek clarification or suggest improvements, not for asking followup questions.